# Velleman's How to Prove It - Analyzing Logical Forms - Quantifiers

Tags: logic

I am having a confusion on the following examples that is provided by Vellman's How to Prove It.

---

Example One: Analyze the logical forms of the following statements.

- Susan likes everyone who dislikes Joe.

The solution that is provided by the book is as follows:

We could think of this as as meaning "If a person dislikes Joe then Susan likes that person"

Let $L(x, y)$ stand for "$x$ likes $y$"; $s$ for Susan and $j$ for Joe

The logical form representation would be $\forall x (\lnot L(x, j) \rightarrow L(s, x))$.

---

Example Two: Analyze the logical forms of the following statements.

- Everyone who Patricia likes, Sue doesn't like.

The solution that is provided:

Let $L(x, y)$ stand for "$x$ likes $y$"; $p$ stand for Patricia and $s$ for Sue

The logical form representation would be $\forall x(L(p, x) \rightarrow \lnot L(s, x))$.

---

My confusion is that why is it that the example's statement logical forms are somewhat a converse?

If I were to follow the first example, I would have stated that "If Sue doesn't like someone then Patricia likes someone"

Which would make me say the logical form would be $\forall x (\lnot L(s, x) \rightarrow L(p, x))$. This logical form is a converse of Example Two.

---

How does one deduce the "correct" way interpretation? Moreover, is it possible that Example Two made an error?

Comment: nitpick: It should be: "everyone *whom* Patricia likes, Sue does not like".

Comment: @Henno Brandsma it's nice to see that not _everyone_ is disregarding grammar. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are dealing with 4 people: Sue, Patricia,  Ali, and Brett

Also suppose that Patricia likes Ali, but not Brett, while Sue does not like either Ali or Brett

In this scenario, the statement from the book

> - Everyone who Patricia likes, Sue doesn't like.

is true: the only person Patricia likes is Brett, and indeed Sue does not like Brett

However, your statement:

> "If Sue doesn't like someone then Patricia likes [that] someone"

is false: Sue does not like Ali, but Patricia does not either.

So, these really are different statements

Comment: Thank you, for providing a clear example!

Comment: @Lexical You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

The second statement says that Patricia liking $x$ is prerequisite to Sue not liking $x$.

In other words, there may be people that are disliked by both Sue and Patricia, that is
$$\exists x\, \neg L(s,x)\wedge \neg L(p,x);$$
however, *if* someone is liked by Patricia, *then* Sue doesn't like that person,
 $$\forall x\, L(p,x)\to \neg L(s,x).$$

Comment: _In other words, there are people that are disliked by both Sue and Patricia_

; I would assume what you meant by this as follows

 "If Sue doesn't like someone then Patricia doesn't like someone"

Which would mean:
 - $\forall x (\lnot L(s, x) \rightarrow \lnot L(p, x))$
 - which is equivalent to $\forall x( L(p, x) \rightarrow L(s, x))$ via (Contrapositive law)

If so, thank you so much for the clarification :)

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. What I said is $\exists x\,:\, \neg L(s,x)\wedge \neg L(p,x)$, which is a consequence of the correct interpretation $\forall x\, :\, L(p,x)\to \neg L(s,x)$.

Comment: @Riccardo It is not. You could have $\forall x\,(L(s,x)\land\lnot L(p,x))$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Agreed, I should have said that there may be. I have corrected the answer in view of your comment! Thanks